# Serving static HTML etc and Django from root '/' using nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I have nginx set up to successfully serve a Django website. I'd like to have it *also* serve a directory of HTML files, images, etc. If a URL doesn't match a file in there, the request should go to Django.

Currently I have this (with irrelevant settings removed, e.g. SSL, logging, etc):

```
upstream myproject_server {
  server unix:/webapps/myproject/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  server_name example.com;

  rewrite ^/favicon.ico$ /static/myproject/favicons/favicon.ico last;
  rewrite ^/robots.txt$ /static/myproject/robots.txt last;

  location /static/ {
    # Django's static files
    alias /webapps/myproject/code/myproject/static_collected/;
  }

  location / {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://myproject_server;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

If I have a directory of miscellaneous files like this at `/webapps/myproject/code/myproject/static_html/`:

```
static_html/
  test.html
  directory/
    foo.html
    bar.png
    another/
      hello.pdf
  etc...
```

What do I need to add to my `nginx.conf` so that those files are efficiently served at `/test.html`, `/directory/foo.html`, etc?

Comment: You could add a `root` statement as `root /webapps/myproject/code/myproject/static_html;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for that! It works, although I'd like requests for a directory to serve any `index.html` inside it. It sounds like that should be default behaviour, but it doesn't work for me (while requests for any `dir/index.html` directory work). I've tried setting `index index.html;` in various places, but with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `root` statement to find files in the `static_html` directory. Your `-f` only checks file existence and not directory existence, so URIs pointing to a directory are sent to `proxy_pass`. You could change this to `-e` to check if files or directories exist.
See [`if` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if).

For example:

```
location / {
    root /webapps/myproject/code/myproject/static_html;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://myproject_server;
    }
}
```

---

However, the preferred solution would probably be to avoid the `if` block altogether. See [`try_files` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

For example:

```
location / {
    root /webapps/myproject/code/myproject/static_html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://myproject_server;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. That does work, although I then got an nginx 403 error at `/`, which puzzles me. I've fixed it by adding this: `location = / { try_files noexist @proxy; }` But I'm not sure why it happened in the first place.